# Accessing content of a other page in a Google Wave widget?

Tags: javascript, google-wave

Is there a way of accessing contents of a other page into a Google Wave widget? And also sending post requests to the other server? Like an iframe behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

...yes, there's a little thing called an iframe extension.  If you use this, you can embed the content from any arbitrary web page into a wave.

The trick is that it doesn't look that great unless the page you're embedding is reasonably simple.  Let me see if I can find the reference you need...

Try using this: http://wave-ide.appspot.com/iframe.xml

There are some risks, so be careful that you only use this widget to embed well-behaved web content (some javascript and URLs that redirect can cause breakage.)

Good luck!

---v